# Fetching data from a website into a Mobile Application

Tags: android, fetch

I am trying to fetch some data from my website, my website is a hotel booking website where I can book/reserve rooms, then the app will be as a reporting app, all the data that comes from the website will be directly go to the app, all the **number of bookings, number of reservations, free rooms, will be directly go to the reporting app**

Any tip on how to do it? I am using Android Studio.

if you needed other information just comment and I will answer them at the comment section or update the question, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 options, make your site mobile friendly and don't bother creating an app or learn about [Webservices, I'd go for a Rest Webservice](http://www.studytonight.com/rest-web-service/), **create** one and, only then, learn how to integrate it with your app.

If you already have a Webservice, I don't know from your question, learning [Retrofit](https://futurestud.io/tutorials/retrofit-getting-started-and-android-client) or [OkHttp](https://teamtreehouse.com/library/making-an-http-get-request-with-okhttp) is a good starting point.

Comment: thanks for the info sir @vithoriop, I should start learning those now.